# how to convert the word column to be the header columns and the name of the 2 articles to be the header of the rows?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, anaconda, tf-idf

I wrote a code that shows the data frame without the headers, only numbers instead

now it looks like that:

```
    1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17
0   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.000000 0.000174   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.000000
1   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.000087 0.000000   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0000
```

and I need to convert it to be like that(without the heading indexes)

```
                word1 word2 word3..................................
    1987_1    data data .............

    1987_2    data data.............................
```

I wrote this code to get to the data frame:

```
# %matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import sklearn as sk
import math 

data = pd.read_csv('D:\\Datasets\\dt.csv', index_col ="word")
dt=data.head(18)
# retrieving row by loc method
#first=data.iloc[:, [1]].values
first=dt["1987_1"]
second=dt["1987_2"]

row1=pd.DataFrame(first) 
row2=pd.DataFrame(second) 

def computeTF(article):
  tf = []
  for i in article: 
    cal=i/11463
    #i+=1
    #print(cal)
    tf.append(cal)
return tf

#running our sentences through the tf function:
#header = data.iloc[0]
tfFirst = computeTF(first)
tfSecond = computeTF(second)
#Converting to dataframe for visualization
dt.columns = dt.iloc[0]
print(dt)
tf_df= pd.DataFrame([tfFirst, tfSecond])
print(tf_df)
```

Do you have any sugestions?